# Upgrading nginx to latest stable 1.20 but reverts to 1.18 when reinstalling modules in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Nginx 1.20.1 by following the following this guide: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147144/how-to-upgrade-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04/1148829#1148829). I was able to upgrade to version 1.20 but during the upgrade process it removed a few modules like the following:

```
libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam 
libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge 
libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext
```

When reinstalling the modules(`sudo apt-get install -y`), it would uninstall v1.20 and go back to 1.18, I tried removing the modules before running the upgrade process but the same will still occur.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How did you upgrade to 1.20?

Comment: I upgreaded by following this guide over https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147144/how-to-upgrade-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04/1148829#1148829

Answer (score 4):

nginx.org packaging of nginx and Ubuntu packaging are not equal and they are not compatible.

You need to either compile the additional modules for nginx 1.20 yourself, or find a source that includes these modules for v1.20.